# Why is this var in angular not updating?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller called `VforumController` and a model called `VforumModel`

`VforumController`

```
VforumJS.controller('VforumController', function($scope, VforumModel)
{
        $scope.currentIndex = 0;
        $scope.presentationData.location = "http://a.web.url";

        $scope.currentSlide = VforumModel.getImage({
            'type' : 'slide',
            'index' : $scope.currentIndex + 1,
            'location' : $scope.presentationData.location
        });
});
```

`VforumModel`

```
VforumJS.service('VforumModel', function($http)
{
    return {
        getImage: function($data)
        {
            return $http.post('resources/auth.php', $data, {timeout:20000}).success(function(response)
            {
                console.log(response); //this outputs the correct data I need to the console
                return response;
            });
        }
    }
})
```

When I do the `console.log(response)`, I can see the data I need, however, the value in my controller isn't updating. I assume `$scope.currentSlide` would turn into the data I am looking for. In my case, its a hashed URL returned from a PHP script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http` returns a promise so you need to wait for it to load and then assign it. You dont communicate directly through return values of the promise "success/then/error" chain.  All communication is done via promise objects. You "wait" for something to happen, and once it does it calls you...  They are alway so hard to explain...

```
VforumJS.service('VforumModel', function($http){
    return {
      getImage: function($data){
          return $http.post('resources/auth.php', $data, {timeout:20000});
      }
    }
}); 

VforumModel.getImage({
'type' : 'slide',
'index' : $scope.currentIndex + 1,
'location' : $scope.presentationData.location
}).success(function(response) {
       $scope.currentSlide = response;
    }
);
```

Comment: I thought returning the response in the success would work? Are you referring to this in the model? Am I writing my $http post wrong?

Comment: Returning the response does nothing in success... you can actually just do the above in the success... one sec.

Comment: Wow, this totally opened up my eyes to a better way of doing some of the work with the models. I've often done a `$broadcast` because I couldn't get data to return properly. This is awesome! I know what you mean trying to explain. I have to explain some of what I'm doing to my boss sometimes..ay yi yi. Thanks so much man, this has been quite helpful